# Can a verb come after a conjunction

Tags: conjunctions, subject-verb-inversion

Can a verb come after a conjunction taking example of this sentence:

> Please Forward This Code **And** **Notify** Website Developer To Paste It Before `</head>` Tag And Make Please Get It Upload The HTML File In The Attachment And Need Html And Xml Sitemap

The question is that here **And** is a conjunction and **Notify** is a verb is it right to use a verb after a  conjunction or we can say can a conjunction become a subject

Comment: A verb after *and* is okay. "And Make Please Get It Upload The HTML File In The Attachment And Need Html And Xml Sitemap" doesn't make any sense though.

Comment: ok means and can be a subject of a sentence if used as

Comment: No, the conjunction is not a subject. The second clause has the same subject as the first one. "He fell down and broke his leg" -- "He" is the subject of both "fell" and "broke"

Comment: The kids hopped and skipped and jumped.

Comment: //Please forward this code and notify the website developer to paste it before 'some noun', tag and make....// After this, it confuses. Is it, ...Please get it. Upload....,OR, Please get it uploaded... [I am unable to relate the sentence after this]. Not sure, if it is my problem, or the sentence needs improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine to have a verb after a conjunction.

> He fell down and broke his leg.

The subject of both clauses is "he". It's short for

> He fell down and he broke his leg.

Comment: ok i have got the answer i was looking